# Windows Phone 8.1 XAML: Pull down to refresh

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, pull-to-refresh

I have been a lot of time looking an way to do "pull down to refresh" in a ScrollViewer or a ListBox, ListViewer... whathever.

The problem is that there is no way to do that in Windows 8.1, I've find some solutions for W7 or even W8, but not for W8.1, and no, there's no way to adapt that jobs to W8.1.

Any knows any way to do this behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried a million ways and none of them worked. At least not without significant flaws. Spare yourself some anger and wait for win10... 

Answer (score 1):

This page helped me http://iwindroid.me/tag/windows-phone-8-1-rt/

I could not compile the one suggested by Ateik. Would be fine if solving the problems, it looks promising but at the moment it has some errors: Syntax Error found in XBF generation

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I found is using Teleriks RadDataBoundListBox: http://www.telerik.com/windows-universal-ui/databoundlistbox

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple control that implements the "Pull to refresh" feature, and the "Load data on demand", you can find it in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedListview), read about it from [this blog post](http://www.tareqateik.com/extendedlistview-control-for-universal-apps-pull-to-refresh-load-more-data-on-demand). Works on both Windows 8 & Windows Phone 8.1

[image]

Comment: In Universal project with xaml in Shared, it throws the following error: Syntax Error found in XBF generation